RDLC POS report printing
Im trying to figure out a way to print in a POS printer without knowing the height of the print.
The idea to dynamically fill a RDLC report with elements in a tree view (that's done) and then send it to silent printing. This is where it gets tricky. The report size its set to the default POS size (80mm to 3276mm)
The idea its to start with a height (need to experiment what value fits best)
And then start adding based on the number of items being aggregated to the report so it would be something like this
double paperWidthMm = report_imprime_comanda.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize.Width;
 double totalHeight = 30;

 foreach (TreeNode parentNode in parentNodes)
 {
     if (parentNode.Tag is Comanda comandaMain)
     {
         double itemHeight = GetItemHeight(comandaMain);
         totalHeight += itemHeight;
         filteredComandas.Add(comandaMain);

    
     }
}

   // Dynamically set the page height based on total content height
   int paperWidthHundredthsOfInch = (int)(paperWidthMm / 25.4 * 100);
   int paperHeightHundredthsOfInch = (int)(totalHeight / 25.4 * 100);
  

PageSettings pageSettings = new PageSettings

  {

      PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", paperWidthHundredthsOfInch, paperHeightHundredthsOfInch)


  };

  MessageBox.Show("Paper Size: " + pageSettings, "Tamaño papel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
 report_imprime_comanda.SetPageSettings(pageSettings);

 // Bind filtered data to the report
 report_imprime_comanda.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 report_imprime_comanda.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Comandas", filteredComandas));

 // Refresh the report to apply the changes
 report_imprime_comanda.RefreshReport();
 PrintPOS printPOS = new PrintPOS();
 // Render and print the report
 printPOS.PrintReportToPrinter(report_imprime_comanda.LocalReport, printerName);



This the function that adds inches to the report based on the elements:
 private double GetItemHeight(Comanda item)
  {
      // Base height for each comanda item
      double baseHeight = 30;

      // Additional height for each child note
      double noteHeight = 15;

      // Calculate total height
      double totalHeight = baseHeight;

      // Split the notes by ';' to count them
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.NOTAS))
      {
          string[] notes = item.NOTAS.Split(';');
          totalHeight += notes.Length * noteHeight;
      }

      return totalHeight;
  }


This is function that does the actual print
 public void PrintReportToPrinter(LocalReport report, string printerName)
    {
        // Configure print settings for the POS printer
        PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
        {
            PrinterName = printerName,
            Copies = 1,
            PrintToFile = false,
        };

        // Create a PrintDocument object
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument
        {
            PrinterSettings = printerSettings
        };

        printDoc.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Render the report to an image
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;

            byte[] bytes = report.Render(
                "Image", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension,
                out streamIds, out warnings);

            using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)))
            {
                args.Graphics.DrawImage(image, args.MarginBounds);
                args.HasMorePages = false;
            }
        };

        // Print the document
        printDoc.Print();
    }

}



If there is a more simple way. I'm all ears.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance !
Im expecting to print directly to a POS printer with dynamic data.

Send data to the printer IP address instead of using the driver.  The driver is adding predefined control characters to the file.

POS printers may not work correctly with Windows in the same way as, say, a lazer printer, as those are generally fixed size pages (A4, 11x13 etc).  What you are doing is basically creating an infinitely sized bitmap, and sending that to the printer as an image.  Depending on what you are actually printing (which looks like mostly text), you could send instructions directly to the printer, as you generate each line.

@Neil I really want to use reports since it will help me with customization and to keep some order in the code. Can you tell me an example of what you are referring to take a look at?
thanks !

What printer are you using?  Does it even support 'bitmap' printing? You don't actually say what the problem is.  Does you solution not work?

the print works but the size is way off. So its either too big or to small. Im using a ZKTCO model ZKP8012 for testing.
